# Property implementation must have its declaration in interface 'FirstViewController'

Tags: objective-c, properties, declaration, synthesize

I am new to Objective-C and am very noobish.
I am trying to pass the text from a `UITextField` in the `SecondViewController` to the `FirstViewController`.
What I have right now is:

(SecondViewController.h)

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *PrimaryPhone;

@end
```

(FirstViewController.m)

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

@synthesize PrimaryPhone;
```

Then there is the other default items included within the .m file.

But where it says:

```
@synthesize PrimaryPhone;
```

Xcode gives me the error in the title. (Property implementation must have its declaration in interface 'FirstViewController')

Answer (score 0):

You must have the property primaryPhone inside FirstViewController.h

Alternatively within the interface

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

In FirstViewController.m

What you are trying to synthesize is belonging to an object of type FirstViewController, but it is declared in a class of type SecondViewController.